# Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in VS2010 for MOSS 2007

Tags: web-part, visual-studio

I have been using VS2010 for developing web parts and deploying them to MOSS 2007 for quite some time. Unfortunately, I had to work on a fresh copy of WINDOWS with all software including MOSS 2007 & VS2010 installed. I create a simple Hello world webpart and build it, it builds fine. When I try packaging it, it says

> Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help will be deply appreciated. I have been trying the solution from last 2 hours, but no luck :(
Edited..Code below:

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class WebPart1 : WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Hello, world!  Compiled in Visual Studio 2010!" });
    }
}
```

Comment: May I Know why the question was downvoted?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot add comment. If you have this exception, you tries to access to the object that is not created. In this case stack trace or log messages are helpful.

Comment: @Alexander...A simple webpart printing "Hello world" is giving this error. Not sure, why..what classes may I be referencing that can throw this error? Any ideas?

Comment: What code's in your web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ended with up creating solution as described [here](http://www.niteshluharuka.com/2011/11/how-to-create-a-wsp-file-manually/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do a [little hacking](http://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/1466821/mobile). I hope, this approach will solve your problem.

Comment: its the same solution posted by Corey Roth at dotnetmafia. I have followed the same but no luck :(

Comment: are you sure that the solution uses version 12 DLLs and you removed SharePoint version attribute from solution schema?

Comment: yes..checked in references and manually removed them..

Comment: you opened your MOSS2007 server, copied Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll to the folder in your solution, add references to these DLLs. and now you can see 12.0.0.0 version af DLLs in references properties. Am I right? I would like to be sure that you did not add the 14 DLLs again.

Comment: yes, the server I am developing does not hv installed MOSS 2010 installed..

Comment: do you use [these downgrade actions](http://www.estruyf.be/blog/downgrade-a-sharepoint-2010-visual-web-part-to-sharepoint-2007/)? if yes, you need to remove items from your project and add them back one at a time to get the package to work.

Comment: mine is not a VWP, still I have tried deleting and re-adding..doesn't work!

Comment: sorry, but without more details I cannot help you. :(

Comment: what details do you need more..I will try my best to give to you.

Comment: did you try to yse 3rd paty tools to create package? maybe it will give some stack trace...

Comment: No,I didn't try any 3rd party!